# MySQL select 1000 increment numbers

Tags: mysql, increment

Is there any possibility to select increment numbers, like:

```
num
1000
1001
1002
1003
1004
...
1999
```

I've tried:

```
set @i=999;
select @i:=@i+1 as num
limit 1000
```

and also:

```
set @i=999;
select @i:=@i+1 as num
where @i <1999;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to operate on a 1000 row table to get what you want:

```
SELECT @i := @i+1 AS num
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
) AS t
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
) AS s
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
) AS u
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := 999) AS var
```

Using `CROSS JOIN` on a 10 by 10 by 10 table combination we get a 1000 row in-line table. Using this as a basis we can calculate the required sequence of `@i` values.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/10217)

Comment: Thank You :) But if I want to select numbers between 123450000 and 123459999 how should I modify this code?

Comment: @Kris Simply change `@i` initialization, i.e. from `CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := 999)` to `CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := 123450000)`. Also, if you want 10,000 numbers instead of 1,000 you have to add another 10 valued inline table, so as to get the required cartesian product of 10,000 rows.

Comment: Thank You. Perfect solution, but is it possible that the numbering starts with 123450000 and ended on 123459999? In Your example starts with 123450001 and ended on 123460000.

Comment: Is there a chance that this query do insert like: `INSERT INTO tbl (num) your_awesome_select`

Comment: @Kris Yes, this is pretty straightforward: look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14862/1).

Comment: Ok, typo mistake `INSET` instead of the `INSERT`. Thanks for best answer

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming (probably wrongly) that you are attempting to select rows based on an auto incremented primary key, seeing this is MySQL?

Would the "BETWEEN" keyword be of better use, instead of using variables?

For example, if you wanted to select rows from table 'myTable', and 'num' is the primary key:

```
SELECT num FROM myTable
WHERE num BETWEEN 999 AND 1999
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple query to print number 1000 - 1999 with a set increment value.

```
DECLARE @firstNumber INT
DECLARE @lastNumber INT
DECLARE @incrementBy INT

SET @firstNumber = 1000
SET @lastNumber = 1999
SET @incrementBy = 1

CREATE TABLE #TEMP ( number INT) 

WHILE(@firstNumber <= @lastNumber)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES (@firstNumber)
    SET @firstNumber = @firstNumber + @incrementBy
END

SELECT * FROM #TEMP

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Comment: Thanks, but not working: `code`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE(@firstNumber <= @lastNumber)`code`